# Mysql performance sending data

Tags: mysql, performance

I've got a table that looks like this:

ID (INT, 9, UNIQUE KEY) --- Item (INT, 3) --- Userid (INT, 9) --- Position (VARCHAR, 12)

Now I want to run the folling query:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM table
WHERE Position LIKE  'BAG%'
AND Userid = ".USERID."
```

The only possible Positions for those cases would be "BAG0", "BAG1", [...], "BAG6"
And those are always unique - that means that there is no Userid that has two Items in BAG2, for example.
But it's not always unique - for example two rows having "Userid: 82378, Positon: 'BOX1'" is possible
Even if I try the IN()-Clause doesn't change the result.

The "Sending data"-time for this query is always about 50ms.

Do you have any ideas how I could modify this table so this query works faster?

Comment: and you need it faster than `your server` can do it because ...?

Comment: Because this is one of the slowest query that needs to be executed when loading the page. And it needs to be executed every time you do something on my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM table
WHERE Position LIKE 'BAG%' AND
      Userid = ".USERID.";
```

This is a pretty simple query.  The only way you can speed it up is by using an index.  I would suggest a composite index of `table(UserId, Position)`.  MySQL should optimize the `like` because the initial prefix is constant.  But, if you want to be really, really sure the index gets used, you can do:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM table
WHERE Position in ('BAG0', 'BAG1', 'BAG2', 'BAG3', 'BAG4', 'BAG5', 'BAG6') and
      Userid = ".USERID.";
```

Comment: Yes, but there may also be multiple rows that have the same Userid and Position (but are NOT LIKE 'BAG%'). Only 'BAG%' + Userid is unique

Comment: @TobiasBaumeister . . . Interesting observation, but it doesn't affect my answer.  The index is not assuming uniqueness at any level.

Comment: Oh, I see - I'll try this :) I mixed it up with the primary key, sorry